# Unable to launch my android application

Tags: android, android-emulator, launch

I am unable to view my application in the emulator. I have tried increasing the adb timeout to 10000 ms. The result is the same. Please tell me what the problem is.

**Console Output:**

```
[2014-09-22 12:52:51 - NotificationExample] ------------------------------
[2014-09-22 12:52:51 - NotificationExample] Android Launch!
[2014-09-22 12:52:51 - NotificationExample] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-22 12:52:51 - NotificationExample] Performing com.example.notificationexample.Notification activity launch
[2014-09-22 12:52:51 - NotificationExample] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_7_2012_by_Google'
[2014-09-22 12:52:51 - NotificationExample] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Nexus_7_2012_by_Google'
[2014-09-22 12:54:07 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1024MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 768MB.
[2014-09-22 12:54:09 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2014-09-22 12:54:09 - Emulator] 
[2014-09-22 12:54:11 - NotificationExample] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-09-22 12:54:11 - NotificationExample] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-09-22 13:00:17 - NotificationExample] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-22 13:00:17 - NotificationExample] Uploading NotificationExample.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-22 13:00:20 - NotificationExample] Installing NotificationExample.apk...
[2014-09-22 13:02:53 - NotificationExample] Failed to install NotificationExample.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-09-22 13:02:53 - NotificationExample] (null)
[2014-09-22 13:02:54 - NotificationExample] Launch canceled!
[2014-09-22 13:04:07 - NotificationExample] ------------------------------
[2014-09-22 13:04:07 - NotificationExample] Android Launch!
[2014-09-22 13:04:07 - NotificationExample] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-22 13:04:07 - NotificationExample] Performing com.example.notificationexample.Notification activity launch
[2014-09-22 13:04:08 - NotificationExample] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_7_2012_by_Google'
[2014-09-22 13:04:08 - NotificationExample] Uploading NotificationExample.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-22 13:04:13 - NotificationExample] Installing NotificationExample.apk...
[2014-09-22 13:06:38 - NotificationExample] Failed to install NotificationExample.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-09-22 13:06:38 - NotificationExample] (null)
[2014-09-22 13:06:49 - NotificationExample] Failed to install NotificationExample.apk on device 'emulator-5554': null
[2014-09-22 13:06:49 - NotificationExample] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
[2014-09-22 13:06:49 - NotificationExample] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Could you run your emulator?

Comment: Yes.The Home screen is displayed but I cannot unlock it.

Comment: There is also possibility the emulator setting is wrong maybe you could post the screenshot of the emulator setting?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Virtual Device has a valid SD card size (i.e. bigger than 0)

Comment: Thank you. I gave the SD card size as 10 MiB. The problem is solved now.